# finding a pattern

Tags: linux

I need to find how many different occurrences of a string *.dbm exist in a group of files.
ie. I have these 2 different strings in the same file name
test1.dbm
test2.dbm
so in file1_10172017.txt there exists test1.dbm
and in a different file1_10162017.txt there exists a string test2.dbm,

I need to find how many different occurrences of (*.dbm) exist in a group of files with the same name(they differ by a timestamp)

Comment: Would make the help easier if you could give us a snippet of how the input file actually looks like.

Comment: Merge your accounts, Trent, or register [this initial one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/257533/trent-tyson) so that you can edit your original post.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it recursively in the entire directory where all `fx273014_w_new_qul_[timestamp].txt` are located

```
grep -ohr "\w*\.dbm" /path/to/dir | sort -u
```

From `man grep`

```
-h, --no-filename
    Suppress the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default
    when there is only  one  file  (or only standard input) to search.
-o, --only-matching
    Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
    with each such part on a separate output line.
-R, -r, --recursive
         Recursively search subdirectories listed.
```

If you want to count every different occurrence, just add a `wc -l` at the end of the command

```
grep -ohr "\w*\.dbm" /path/to/dir | sort -u | wc -l
```

Or do it for the files you want without doing it recursively

```
grep -oh "\w*\.dbm" /path/to/fx273014_w_new_qul_* | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Yeah, you probably only need  "\w*\.dbm". You could also add the literal filename that the op is using. `fx273014_w_new_xw_qul_*`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly the second time around, this will show you all the unique occurrences

```
grep .dbm file1* | sort -u
```

If you only want to know how many different then pipe it again:

```
grep .dbm file1* | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: This won't work since you'd get the whole line not only the "blabla.dbm" part. So every hit will still be "uniq" even if it's the same name in a different line.

Comment: True, it's not too clear what the contents of the file is, I assumed it was only those strings on the line.